# Reuse same framgent object in FragmentTransaction android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to add a fragment(B) inside another fragment(A).
and using the code as below.

```
Fragment fragmentB = new FragmentB();
public void navigateToFragmentB(){

//adding some data to fragmentB.
//fragmentB.addQueryParams();

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentARootLayout, fragmentB);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Let's say, At first, i am trying to inflate fragmentB inside FragmentA with some QueryParams queryParamOld. It's working fine.  Now, The problem arises 
when i am trying to inflate fragmentB again with some different QueryParams queryParamNew. It's not working. Can someone help me to find out the solution?

one possible solution is to move Fragment fragmentB = new FragmentB() inside method(navigateToFragmentB()). But, I don't want to re-create
object.

Comment: how is "it's not working" ?

Comment: The new layout is not being inflated, doing nothing.

Comment: you should post your code - which call navigateToFragmentB() and also inflate Query Params